# Implementing independent operations in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following situation.
I have an operation A running in a thread, say, T1. Now what I want to do is to launch another operation, say B from this thread T1 but I want B to be independent of A and T1, i.e., after launching operation B, T1 should continue to do what it was doing and terminate while B can continue to do it's work until it's work is finished (irrespective of whether T1 has terminated or not).

I want B to be completely independent of T1 or A and should allow T1 to terminate irrespective of B's current state.

I am using .net 4.0 and not .net 4.5

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thread can spawn other threads whose termination is independent of the thread that spawned it. EDIT: Wow, let me see if I can word that properly. Feel free to spawn more background threads from T1, they'll be independent.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Thanks for your response. But how? If I spawn a foreground thread then it won't let the parent thread to terminate until it has terminated itself and if I spawn a background thread then it will terminate silently when parent thread terminates. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you spawning your threads?

Comment: Thread t = new Thread([delegate]);

Comment: The word your question is missing is 'process'. You need to launch a separate process if you want your thread to continue living when the current process dies.

Comment: @Rotem - Wow! I was thinking on the same lines. Any syntax hints?

Comment: That should be fine Kumar. Unless the terminating thread is your application GUI thread, or you're trying to wait/join then it should be fine.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: @KumarVaibhav: You are confused regarding what background/foreground threads are. There is just one difference, and it is clearly spelled out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx).

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I tried Chris but it's blocking the parent :(

Comment: @KumarVaibhav Maybe give [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) a shot.

Comment: If you want a general review of different threading mechanisms this [chapter](http://www.albahari.com/threading/ "Threading in C#") from C# in a Nutshell might help

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest you to use `Tasks` instead of threads. here is code

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // starting your thread A
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ThreadAWork);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Thread A's method
    private static void ThreadAWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:A Started");
        // starting Thread B from Thread A
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ThreadBWork);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:A Stopped");
    }

    // Thread B's method
    private static void ThreadBWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:B Started");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:B Stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any thread can spawn other threads whose termination is independent of the thread that spawned it.

Feel free to spawn more background threads from T1, they'll be independent.

EDIT: Perhaps you're implementing the threading incorrectly that's creating blocks and dependencies. Perhaps try leveraging the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how? If I spawn a foreground thread then it won't let the parent thread to terminate until it has terminated itself and if I spawn a background thread then it will terminate silently when parent thread terminates. Am I missing something?

Comment: May be. I am taking a re - look at the code. I'll keep this thread updated in case of any progress. Thanks.